# Wireless router crashes exactly every half hour

Tags: router, wireless-router

I have a wireless ADSL router for my home network.  Lately (and I don't remember when this started), the router has started crashing & rebooting every half hour.  Exactly.  At hh:03 and hh:33.  No clue as to why this is, but it is totally predictable.

Some clues from watching the lights on the panel: The following LEDs are on the box:

- Power
- SYS
- Wireless
- Link/Act
- SyncMode
- LAN 1-4
- ADSL
- Internet

In normal, functioning mode, all the LEDs are on solidly, except for the LAN ports (I only use wireless) and the "Wireless" light, which flickers.

At hh:03 and hh:33, the following happens:

1. The "Link/Act" (and SyncMode?) LED starts flashing
2. After a minute or so, the 4 LAN LEDs all flash on and off.
3. Then the ADSL and Internet LEDs switch off, and it looks like the reconnection process starts again, with first ADSL, then Internet lighting up again.

I tried videoing the lights so I could record the sequence of events more accurately, but the light didn't work out so well...

Any ideas where to start with this?

EDIT: Here's a screen shot of my config.  Does this tell us anything useful?

[image]

Comment: Which router? Did you try a complete reset?

Comment: @Karan - it's an Israeli product: PowerNet PAR-720G.  Couldn't find any English documentation!  But the router's web page is in English.

Comment: Is it possible that you accidentally enabled scheduled reboots on the router?

Comment: @Breakthrough Do you think there would be such a setting?  I went looking through the router config, but couldn't find any such thing.  Why would there be such a setting, anyway?

Comment: Yes, among others, Netgear has a scheduled reboot, which was a convenient way of clearing out router table and memory buffer issues to prevent router lockup.

Comment: How often does your router renew its IP from the service provider? Check the lease time of the service provider IP. Is your telephone line quiet when the router is misbehaving?

Comment: @FiascoLabs - funny thing is, I tried the theory that it's rebooting every half hour, and I restarted the whole box at hh:15.  Came hh:33, and it still rebooted!  But now, as I write this at hh:15 an integral number of hours later... the router just reset itself again!  Holy hell, am I creating black holes in my router's hourly schedule?

Comment: @Ali - added a screen shot of something that looks like lease time.  Do those settings look OK?

Comment: @Shaul - These are the lease times the router uses for machines connected to it. The lease times of your service provider will be on the page that shows your external IP and ISP DNS servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it was a fault with the router.  I took it back to my internet provider and they happily swapped it...